# Django: stop saving the same value in the database

Tags: django

My gorgeous friends on the internet.
I have a problem with my `Django` app, implementing a function not to save the same value in the database. When I hit `command + r` on a Macbook Air, my app saves the previous value in the form although the form was empty. If someone knows how to stop, please let me know.
Here is the code below.

```
@login_required
def blog(request, pk):
    blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=pk)
    comments = Comment.objects.order_by('-created').filter(blog=blog.id)
    number_of_comments = comments.count()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = CommentForm()
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.blog = blog
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.save()
            form = CommentForm()
```

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, redirect
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from .models import Blog, Comment
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
from django.db.models import Q
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger, Paginator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from .forms import CommentForm
from base.choices import category_choices
# Create your views here.


@login_required
def index(request):
    # Add 'NEW!!' if a blog was created yesterday or today
    today = datetime.today()
    yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)
    today_created_blogs = Blog.objects.all().filter(
        is_public='公開', created__date=today)
    yes_created_blogs = Blog.objects.all().filter(
        is_public='公開', created__date=yesterday)
    today_updated_blogs = Blog.objects.all().filter(
        is_public='公開', updated__date=today)
    yes_updated_blogs = Blog.objects.all().filter(
        is_public='公開', updated__date=yesterday)

    count = Blog.objects.order_by(
        '-updated').filter(is_public='公開', created__date=today).count()

    blogs = Blog.objects.order_by('-updated').filter(is_public='公開')[:10]

    # print(f'today -> {today}')
    # print(f'yesterday -> {yesterday}')
    # print(f'today_blogs -> {today_blogs}')
    # print(f'yesterday_blogs -> {yesterday_blogs}')
    # print(f'blogs -> {blogs}')
    # print(f'today blogs -> {count}')

    context = {
        'blogs': blogs,
        'today_created_blogs': today_created_blogs,
        'yes_created_blogs': yes_created_blogs,
        'today_updated_blogs': today_updated_blogs,
        'yes_updated_blogs': yes_updated_blogs,
        'count': count,
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/latest_blogs.html', context)


class BlogList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'blog/all_blogs.html'
    context_object_name = 'blogs'
    ordering = ('-updated')
    paginate_by = 10

    # FoodListと違って、全ユーザーの記事を表示
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset().filter(is_public='公開')
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        today = datetime.today()
        # context['blogs'] = Blog.objects.order_by('-created').filter(is_public='公開')
        yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)
        context['today_created_blogs'] = Blog.objects.all().filter(
            is_public='公開', created__date=today)
        context['yes_created_blogs'] = Blog.objects.all().filter(
            is_public='公開', created__date=yesterday)
        context['today_updated_blogs'] = Blog.objects.all().filter(
            is_public='公開', updated__date=today)
        context['yes_updated_blogs'] = Blog.objects.all().filter(
            is_public='公開', updated__date=yesterday)
        context['category_choices'] = category_choices
        return context
    (category_choices)


@login_required
def all_blogs_search(request):
    # Add 'NEW!!' if a blog was created yesterday or today
    today = datetime.today()
    yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)
    today_created_blogs = Blog.objects.all().filter(
        is_public='公開', created__date=today)
    yes_created_blogs = Blog.objects.all().filter(
        is_public='公開', created__date=yesterday)
    today_updated_blogs = Blog.objects.all().filter(
        is_public='公開', updated__date=today)
    yes_updated_blogs = Blog.objects.all().filter(
        is_public='公開', updated__date=yesterday)

    blogs = Blog.objects.order_by('-updated').filter(is_public='公開')

    # paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 10)
    # page = request.GET.get('page')
    # paged_blogs = paginator.get_page(page)

    if 'keyword1' in request.GET and 'keyword2' in request.GET and 'keyword3' in request.GET:
        keyword1 = request.GET['keyword1']
        keyword2 = request.GET['keyword2']
        keyword3 = request.GET['keyword3']
        if keyword1 and keyword2 and keyword3:
            blogs = blogs.filter(
                # 1
                Q(title__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(content_1__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(content_2__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(content_3__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(user__username__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(tags__name__in=[keyword1]) |
                # 2
                Q(title__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(content_1__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(content_2__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(content_3__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(user__username__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(tags__name__in=[keyword2]) |
                # 3
                Q(title__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(content_1__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(content_2__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(content_3__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(user__username__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(tags__name__in=[keyword3])
            )
        elif keyword1 and keyword2:
            blogs = blogs.filter(
                # 1
                Q(title__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(content_1__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(content_2__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(content_3__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(user__username__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(tags__name__in=[keyword1]) |
                # 2
                Q(title__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(content_1__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(content_2__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(content_3__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(user__username__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(tags__name__in=[keyword2])
            )
        elif keyword1 and keyword3:
            blogs = blogs.filter(
                # 1
                Q(title__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(content_1__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(content_2__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(content_3__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(user__username__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(tags__name__in=[keyword1]) |
                # 2
                Q(title__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(content_1__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(content_2__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(content_3__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(user__username__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(tags__name__in=[keyword3])
            )
        elif keyword2 and keyword3:
            blogs = blogs.filter(
                # 1
                Q(title__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(content_1__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(content_2__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(content_3__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(user__username__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(tags__name__in=[keyword2]) |
                # 2
                Q(title__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(content_1__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(content_2__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(content_3__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(user__username__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(tags__name__in=[keyword3])
            )
        elif keyword1:
            blogs = blogs.filter(
                # 1
                Q(title__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(content_1__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(content_2__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(content_3__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(user__username__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(tags__name__in=[keyword1])
            )
        elif keyword2:
            blogs = blogs.filter(
                # 1
                Q(title__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(content_1__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(content_2__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(content_3__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(user__username__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(tags__name__in=[keyword2])
            )
        elif keyword3:
            blogs = blogs.filter(
                # 1
                Q(title__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(content_1__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(content_2__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(content_3__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(user__username__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(tags__name__in=[keyword3])
            )

    context = {
        'blogs': blogs,
        # 'paged_blogs': paged_blogs,
        'today_created_blogs': today_created_blogs,
        'yes_created_blogs': yes_created_blogs,
        'today_updated_blogs': today_updated_blogs,
        'yes_updated_blogs': yes_updated_blogs,
        'values': request.GET
    }

    return render(request, 'blog/all_blogs.html', context)


@login_required
def my_blogs(request):
    # Add 'NEW!!' if a blog was created yesterday or today
    today = datetime.today()
    yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)
    today_created_blogs = Blog.objects.all().filter(
        is_public='公開', created__date=today)
    yes_created_blogs = Blog.objects.all().filter(
        is_public='公開', created__date=yesterday)
    today_updated_blogs = Blog.objects.all().filter(
        is_public='公開', updated__date=today)
    yes_updated_blogs = Blog.objects.all().filter(
        is_public='公開', updated__date=yesterday)

    blogs = Blog.objects.order_by(
        '-updated').filter(user=request.user, is_public='公開')

    context = {
        'blogs': blogs,
        'today_created_blogs': today_created_blogs,
        'yes_created_blogs': yes_created_blogs,
        'today_updated_blogs': today_updated_blogs,
        'yes_updated_blogs': yes_updated_blogs,
        # 'count': count,
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/my_blogs.html', context)


@login_required
def my_blogs_search(request):
    # Add 'NEW!!' if a blog was created yesterday or today
    today = datetime.today()
    yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)
    today_created_blogs = Blog.objects.all().filter(
        is_public='公開', created__date=today)
    yes_created_blogs = Blog.objects.all().filter(
        is_public='公開', created__date=yesterday)
    today_updated_blogs = Blog.objects.all().filter(
        is_public='公開', updated__date=today)
    yes_updated_blogs = Blog.objects.all().filter(
        is_public='公開', updated__date=yesterday)

    blogs = Blog.objects.order_by(
        '-updated').filter(user=request.user, is_public='公開')

    # paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 10)
    # page = request.GET.get('page')
    # paged_blogs = paginator.get_page(page)

    if 'keyword1' in request.GET and 'keyword2' in request.GET and 'keyword3' in request.GET:
        keyword1 = request.GET['keyword1']
        keyword2 = request.GET['keyword2']
        keyword3 = request.GET['keyword3']
        if keyword1 and keyword2 and keyword3:
            blogs = blogs.filter(
                # 1
                Q(title__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(content_1__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(content_2__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(content_3__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(user__username__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(tags__name__in=[keyword1]) |
                # 2
                Q(title__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(content_1__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(content_2__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(content_3__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(user__username__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(tags__name__in=[keyword2]) |
                # 3
                Q(title__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(content_1__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(content_2__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(content_3__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(user__username__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(tags__name__in=[keyword3])
            )
        elif keyword1 and keyword2:
            blogs = blogs.filter(
                # 1
                Q(title__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(content_1__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(content_2__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(content_3__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(user__username__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(tags__name__in=[keyword1]) |
                # 2
                Q(title__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(content_1__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(content_2__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(content_3__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(user__username__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(tags__name__in=[keyword2])
            )
        elif keyword1 and keyword3:
            blogs = blogs.filter(
                # 1
                Q(title__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(content_1__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(content_2__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(content_3__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(user__username__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(tags__name__in=[keyword1]) |
                # 2
                Q(title__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(content_1__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(content_2__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(content_3__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(user__username__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(tags__name__in=[keyword3])
            )
        elif keyword2 and keyword3:
            blogs = blogs.filter(
                # 1
                Q(title__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(content_1__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(content_2__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(content_3__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(user__username__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(tags__name__in=[keyword2]) |
                # 2
                Q(title__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(content_1__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(content_2__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(content_3__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(user__username__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(tags__name__in=[keyword3])
            )
        elif keyword1:
            blogs = blogs.filter(
                # 1
                Q(title__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(content_1__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(content_2__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(content_3__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(user__username__icontains=keyword1) |
                Q(tags__name__in=[keyword1])
            )
        elif keyword2:
            blogs = blogs.filter(
                # 1
                Q(title__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(content_1__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(content_2__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(content_3__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(user__username__icontains=keyword2) |
                Q(tags__name__in=[keyword2])
            )
        elif keyword3:
            blogs = blogs.filter(
                # 1
                Q(title__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(content_1__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(content_2__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(content_3__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(user__username__icontains=keyword3) |
                Q(tags__name__in=[keyword3])
            )

    context = {
        'blogs': blogs,
        # 'paged_blogs': paged_blogs,
        'today_created_blogs': today_created_blogs,
        'yes_created_blogs': yes_created_blogs,
        'today_updated_blogs': today_updated_blogs,
        'yes_updated_blogs': yes_updated_blogs,
        'values': request.GET
    }

    return render(request, 'blog/my_blogs.html', context)


@login_required
def drafts(request):
    user_drafts = Blog.objects.order_by(
        '-created').filter(user=request.user, is_public='非公開')
    context = {
        # 'user': user,
        'user_drafts': user_drafts,
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/drafts.html', context)


@login_required
def blog(request, pk):
    blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=pk)
    comments = Comment.objects.order_by('-created').filter(blog=blog.id)
    number_of_comments = comments.count()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = CommentForm()
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.blog = blog
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.save()
            form = CommentForm()

    if blog.link_1 is not None or blog.link_2 is not None:
        link_1 = blog.link_1
        link_2 = blog.link_2
        context = {
            'blog': blog,
            'link_1': link_1,
            'link_2': link_2,
            'form': form,
            'comments': comments,
            'number_of_comments': number_of_comments,
        }
    else:
        context = {
            'blog': blog,
            'form': form,
            'comments': comments,
            'number_of_comments': number_of_comments,

        }
    return render(request, 'blog/blog.html', context)


# @login_required
# def add_comment(request, pk):
#   blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=pk)
#   if request.method == 'GET':
#     form = CommentForm()
#   if request.method == 'POST':
#     form = CommentForm(request.POST)
#     if form.is_valid():
#       comment = form.save(commit=False)
#       comment.blog = blog
#       comment.user = request.user
#       comment.save()
#       return redirect('blog', pk=blog.pk)

#   context = {
#     'form': form,
#   }
#   return render(request, 'blog/blog.html', context)

class BlogCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'blog/create.html'
    fields = ['title', 'content_1', 'content_2',
              'content_3', 'link_1', 'link_2', 'tags', 'is_public']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('latest_blogs')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(BlogCreate, self).form_valid(form)


class BlogUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'blog/update.html'
    fields = ['title', 'content_1', 'content_2',
              'content_3', 'link_1', 'link_2', 'tags', 'is_public']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('latest_blogs')


class BlogDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    template_name = 'blog/delete.html'
    model = Blog
    context_object_name = 'blog'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('latest_blogs')


@login_required
def comment_update(request, blog_id, comment_id):
    blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=blog_id)
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=comment_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST, instance=comment)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('blog', pk=blog_id)
    else:
        form = CommentForm(instance=comment)
    context = {
        'blog': blog,
        'comment': comment,
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/comment_update.html', context)


@login_required
def comment_delete(request, blog_id, comment_id):
    blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=blog_id)
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=comment_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment.delete()
        return redirect('blog', pk=blog_id)

    context = {
        'blog': blog,
        'comment': comment,
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/comment_delete.html', context)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show the rest of the view? Ideally after post, you redirect to another page.

Comment: I did, but I don't think it matters.

Comment: In `blog()`, try to send a redirect as a response at the end of the POST handling: `return redirect(reverse('<your blog url>', kwargs={'pk': blog.id})`. Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) on what we are trying to achieve

Comment: I added 'return redirect('blog', pk=blog.id)' at the end of the POST handling, and now it's working as I want!! Your comment gave me a great hint to solve this.

Comment: Great to hear that!